# Podfile depending on alamofire and other pod that depends on alamofire too but different version

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I have a project that depends on Alamofire 5.0 and another pod which depends on an older version of Alamofire 4.9. however I get the error when i compile it.

my pod dependency are as follows:

**Podfile of my project**

```
pod 'Alamofire', '5.0.4'
pod 'MyFramework', '2.0.0'
```

**MyFramework.podspec**

```
s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 4.9.0'
```

Is there any way to make it compilable without changing any codes ? so i want MyFramework keep using the Alamofire 4.9, and in my project it can be used 5.0.4. is that possible to keep both versions of alamofire only for now? I just want to make the compiler happy so that we can compile the code and move forwards and tackle the project and framework separately. any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: You can't have 2 versions of the same library. I think the "easiest" solution for you is to downgrade your project's Alamofire to 4.9.0. There are some ugly workarounds as well, e.g. clone Alamofire 5.0.4, rename it to something else, compile and use that Frankenstein inside your project for now.

Comment: thanks for the tips. seems that the easier way to downgrade only.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible. Cocoapods resolves all dependencies into single Pods project so it can't have multiple versions of the same library in it. You should either update the version in your framework or lower it in your app podfile.

Comment: thanks a lot  for the reply. yes seems i have to lower the version in my project.